# Pages timeout after enabling APC

Tags: php, windows, apache, apc

I have installed APC on our Windows dev server. After I enable APC and restart apache our pages do not load. They timeout and I just get connection was reset on browser.
Other scripts on server such as `phpmyadmin` also does not load.

Here is our system config:

```
Windows 2003 Server
Apache 2.2.22
PHP Version 5.3.15
APC Version 3.1.11
```

Checking on `apc.php` I see hits 80% and misses 20%.

**APC Runtime Settings**

```
apc.cache_by_default    1
apc.canonicalize    1
apc.coredump_unmap    0
apc.enable_cli    0
apc.enabled    1
apc.file_md    50
apc.file_update_protection    2
apc.filters    ''
apc.gc_ttl    3600
apc.include_once_override    0
apc.lazy_classes    0
apc.lazy_functions    0
apc.max_file_size    1M
apc.num_files_hint    1000
apc.preload_path    ''
apc.report_autofilter    0
apc.rfc1867    0
apc.rfc1867_freq    0
apc.rfc1867_name    APC_UPLOAD_PROGRESS
apc.rfc1867_prefix    upload_
apc.rfc1867_ttl    3600
apc.serializer    default
apc.shm_segments    1
apc.shm_size    32M
apc.slam_defense    1
apc.stat    1
apc.stat_ctime    0
apc.ttl    0
apc.use_request_time    1
apc.user_entries_hint    4096
apc.user_ttl    0
apc.write_lock    1
```

I have seen files created on designated temp folder with names such as `.apc.a00532` but they have  `file size 0`

I also checked php error log and I do not see anything there.

Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks in advance.

**Edit**
I am using VC9 compiled PHP and my apache is matching VC9 compiled from apache lounge. I have tried using APC 3.1.9 also and that does not display page also. Any php script I run gives timeout except apc.php itself and there it shows me things are being cached.

Comment: You might see a bit more action over at serverfault.

Comment: I did not want to create cross-site duplicate, If don't get some ideas here might move it to there. Thanks for the advice.

Comment: You arent using Zend Server are you?

Comment: @wes No Zend server apache from apache lounge, php from php.net both VC9 compiled

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe the APC version you're using is not matching your PHP version.
The first thing I should do is to run `php -v` from the command line and check for errors.
Be aware that the APC 3.1.11 version is still beta; the latest stable version is 3.1.9.
You can download the APC precompiled binary version from [here](http://dev.freshsite.pl/php-accelerators/apc.html).
To choose the right APC version (VC6/VC9 - thread-safe/non-thread-safe), you should disable APC and open a "[phpinfo()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.phpinfo.php)" page, then look for the options "**Thread safety**" and "**Configure command**".
If you have downloaded your PHP from the [PHP site](http://windows.php.net/download/#php-5.3), the 5.3.15 version should be VC9 compiled.
This version should not be used with "apache.org" binaries, as you can read [here](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=60645), so you should also use the Apache VC9 version, available from [Apache Lounge](http://www.apachelounge.com/download/).

Comment: Thanks for info. For this setup I have php VC9 and apache VC9 from the sources you have also mentioned. My Apache is from Apache Lounge.
I will edit question to give these info too.

Comment: Its running as Apache module and I just tried running a script after turning on enable_cli option. 
It ran fine and gave me output through cli as expected.

Comment: Yes I have checked tmp folder added to `open_basedir` also I see apc created `C:\Program Files\PHP\temp\apc.XXXXXX` file but it has 0 filesize. 
I also let it to write win\temp and same results.

Comment: Still no response from any script there on browser. From cli I get `open_basedir` restriction error if I set that to empty. FYI normally I have `C:\windows\temp` there under `open_basedir` too. 
I have downloaded sources for php I will try to compile them in my machine.

Comment: Tried setting `open_basedir` to none and using default `php.ini` file. Pages still do not load also now `apc.php` does not load also. At least that became more consistent :D

Comment: APC does load web server starts but when I try `apc.php` that page does not load also with default `php.ini` file. With my custom `.ini` file apc.php page loads and displays hits and misses etc. But other scripts don't load with my custom `.ini` file

Comment: I do but link did not show up so I opened a room since you were there chatting with burning code igniter